# How to resolve Host Key Verification error when building APK

Tags: github, expo, key, apk, host

I am trying to build an apk using expo:

When I run this command `eas build -p android --profile preview` the build starts but it then fails with the following error during yarn install:

```
error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://git@github.com/naver/hammer.js.git
Directory: /home/expo/workingdir/build
Output:
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
yarn install exited with non-zero code: 128
```

I understand that this is due to a matching or missing key, and I have tried the following to resolve it:

I ran this command: `ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` to make sure that GitHub is in the list of known hosts. I ran the build command again and it still failed with the same error. There have been various questions already with similar issues - but none of the proposed solutions seem to be helpful in this particular case. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what else I can try?

Comment: ssh://git@github.com/naver/hammer.js.git doesn't seem to be a public git repo (or doesn't exist anymore), so you need the ssh private key to access this repository.

Comment: Thanks Robert! You are right - it's no longer active. Thanks very much!